# SQL Azure connection closed for large json strings

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, dapper

I'm trying to save a largish json string (c.2Mb) to a NVARCHAR(MAX) column in a SQL Azure database but get the following exception:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)]
```

The INSERT statement works fine if I set the json string to "". I have successfully saved other, smaller json strings with the same method. The exception is thrown immediately so doesn't feel like a timeout. Nevertheless I have tried changing the connection and command timeouts to no avail.

I'm using Dapper to talk to SQL:

```
 public async Task<PublisherDto> SaveNewAsync(PublisherDto publisher, int userID)
    {
        using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString()))
        {
            var b = await cnn.QueryAsync<PublisherDto>("s_PublisherInsert", new
            {
                publisher.cv_id,
                publisher.Name,
                publisher.ThumbImageUrl,
                publisher.FullImageUrl,
                userID,
                publisher.cv_Url,
                publisher.JsonData,
                publisher.cv_version_hash
            }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 60);
            return b.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue and have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting timeout to something higher. As per the documentation the error is related to the timeout.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555938

Hope it helps.

-RN

Comment: "Use a value of zero to wait without an exception being thrown." This fixed it for me, thanks very much.

Comment: Setting the timeout to 0 will push the problem further down the road. Eventually your application writing these JSON objects will slow down below an acceptable limit.  If you need to write lots of large JSON objects, DocumentDB is a better azure solution than Windows Azure SQL Database.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and was unable to diagnose exactly what the source of the problem was, but I introduced a connection resiliency class to automatically retry on failures. Again, while this does not solve or identify the underlying root problem, it did make the application robust to the issue.

I use Entity Framework to connect to Azure SQL, and a basic how-to on implementing a resilient connection using the DbExecutionStrategy is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.aspx).

It looks like you may be connecting using ADO. Here is a useful post on implementing [ADO.NET Connection Resiliency](https://tudorturcu.wordpress.com/2013/11/11/ado-net-connection-resiliency/).

Comment: This is always a good practice when relying on networking. (Sometimes things just fail; if they don't, someone else is transparently handling the errors for you.)

Answer (score 0):

You have set command timeout, but do not mention what is timeout on connection to the db. I would recommend to extend connection timeout in connection string.

Comment: It's set to 30s but the error happens immediately, not after 30s.

Comment: Increase it to something like 360 and give it a shot. It looks like your connection is being severed for some reason.